# What is the CRS for France

Tags: coordinate-system, france

Has anyone any idea what the CRS is for France?  I am new to QGIS (moving over from using Arcgis) and trying to find out basics.  I have found a huge list beginning NTF (Paris) but wonder which one to apply.

Comment: http://georepository.com/crs_27572/NTF-Paris-Lambert-zone-II.html

Answer (score 8):

**Nowadays**

The most common CRS is EPSG 2154 also called RGF93 / Lambert-93 http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2154/ .

It's for covering entire metropolitan France (because we have some isles far away ;) )

For the cadastre, to have more precision, the France is divided in 9 zones (see the following [link](http://georezo.net/blog/parcellair/files//home/georezo/data/prod/blog/wp-content/blogs.dir/12/files/2009/12/zonesRGF93.jpg))

The EPSG code follow the rule "Conique Conforme Zone 42" <=> EPSG 3942, "Conique Conforme Zone 43"<=> EPSG 3943 and so on until the EPSG 3950

**Outdated**

The EPSG 27572 is now outdated (you always can find them in local authorities or in some bad French OpenData datasets but official data have to be in EPSG 2154)

It was the most common code for global metropolitan France.

There was also [4 zones](http://georezo.net/blog/parcellair/files//home/georezo/data/prod/blog/wp-content/blogs.dir/12/files/2009/12/zones_lambert.png) for data requiring more precision.

For those zones, the codes  are 27571, 27572, 27573, 27574 (last digit is the zone number) >> I know it's weird that the zone 2 code is the same as global old code but it's like that.

Comment: to add- if you have a French dataset with XY coordiantes in metres, use EPSG 2154 as mentioned above.